# Linux command to display the contents of a given file byte by byte with the character and its numerical representation displayed for each byte

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command, options

I am looking for the Linux command and option combination to display the contents of a given file byte by byte with the character and its numerical representation.

I was under the impression that in order to do this, I would use the following:

```
od -c [file]
```

However, I have been told this is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: What if your file contain multi-byte characters?

Comment: What do you mean by "numerical representation"?   And who told you it's incorrect?  Please provide input/output you expected.

Comment: @yaegashi This. I'm as uncertain about the matter as you are. There is so much ambiguity. If there was an example output, I'd be better able to interpret what they mean, however, I don't know exactly what they want.

Comment: Is that your homework assignment?

Comment: @yaegashi This is a portion of questions for a homework exercise, yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: you can try `xxd file`

Comment: @meuh Didn't work. I think it is going to be od with some option, but the only option I know of that gives similar results to what I believe the question is asking is -c.

Comment: Ok, then how about `od -t x1c datafile` or `od -t cx1 datafile`.

Comment: @drewbenn Thanks for the condolences. It's actually not from my professor, so there is no relevant source material. It's a third-party program (and this is my second semester dealing with its oddities). I've had times when I've legitimately given (a) 100% correct answer(s) and just been told I'm wrong. Don't mean to drop my problems on UL exchange, but I'm stumped.

Comment: @yaegashi Thanks for trying, friend. It's not taking. I'm getting no feedback from it, really. Just giving it what looks to be perfectly fine solutions without any reasoning for its rejection.

Comment: I'm sorry but we can't really answer this. There are way too many possible answers and for all we know, this test of yours needs `od -cb < file` instead of `od -c -b file` or `od -cb file` or whatever. There are perfectly valid solutions I can think of using little perl scripts as well. All of these are correct but we have no way of knowing which one your test is expecting so all we can do is throw random answers out there. I'm going to close this as too broad. You can tell your teachers that any such test that only accepts a single answer is simply ridiculous.

Comment: @terdon That's perfectly fine. I understand. Just trying to get some extra perspective. I appreciate the help, folks (and your answer worked, by the way).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key is

> the character and its numerical representation

so `-c` only gives you half of that. One solution is

```
od -c -b file
```

but of course there are lots of different number representations to choose from.

Answer (score 6):

How about [`hexdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) or `hd`?  Try

```
hexdump -C [file]
```

Comment: No dice. Still incorrect.